# How to create a /sys attribute with variable name

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to create an attribute file under /sys with a variable name?
example:

```
char *variable_name = foo;
/* Create an attribute file foo */
struct kobj_attribute test = __ATTR(variable_name,0660,_show,_store);
```

Comment: Please elaborate more verbose what you are actually trying to accomplish, because I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into kernel development. But: If you do this:

```
find /sys -type f -name '*1*'
```

you should find some examples, where other code is doing what you're seeking for. So, I'd just grab those as examples and look, how they do it. One example could be the machine check exception code:

```
[...]
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck4/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck5/bank1
[...]
$ ls /sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank*
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank0
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank1
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank2
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank3
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank4
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank5
/sys/devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck0/bank6
```

In any case, it seems like you have to reimplement the __ATTR macro for this (i.e. initialize the kobj_attribute struct yourself).

Answer (score 0):

The macros __ATTR make stringify your variable.
Look at [sysfs.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h#L100)

The __stringify macros is:

```
#define __stringify_1(x...)     #x
#define __stringify(x...)       __stringify_1(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

see samples/kobject/kobject-example.c under a Linux kernel tree for an example of how to create an attribute file under /sys